# Android Table orientation vertical

Tags: android, layout

I working on a table feature right now and I don't know how to change the oriëntation of a table.

This is my horizontal view, this is what I expect for the horizontal view:

[image]

And my code for the horizontal view.:

```
private void setupTable() {
    setStretchAllColumns(true);
    setBackground(borderDrawable(mTableBorderWidth));
    setPadding(mTableBorderWidth, mTableBorderWidth, mTableBorderWidth, mTableBorderWidth);

    for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow <= 1; currentRow++) {
        tableRow = new TableRow(mContext);

        if (currentRow == 0) {

            for (int h = 0; h < tableData.field_options.options.size(); h++) {
                textView = new TextView(mContext);
                textView.setTextColor(mTextColor);
                textView.setBackground(borderDrawable(mTextViewBorderWidth));
                textView.setText(tableData.field_options.options.get(h).label);
                textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                textView.setPadding(0, 6, 0, 6);
                textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                tableRow.addView(textView);
            }
        } else {

            for (int currentColumn = 0; currentColumn < tableData.field_options.options.size(); currentColumn++) {
                editText = new EditText(mContext);
                editText.setTextColor(mTextColor);
                editText.setBackground(borderDrawable(mTextViewBorderWidth));
                editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                editText.setPadding(0, 6, 0, 6);
                tableRow.addView(editText);
            }
        }
        addView(tableRow);
    }
}
```

And this is my vertical view right now:

[image]

My code of the vertical table. I set the orientation here with Linear.Vertical but it doesn't help:

```
private void setupVerticalTable() {
    setStretchAllColumns(true);
    setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    setBackground(borderDrawable(mTableBorderWidth));
    setPadding(mTableBorderWidth, mTableBorderWidth, mTableBorderWidth, mTableBorderWidth);


    for (int h = 0; h < tableData.field_options.options.size(); h++) {
        tableRow = new TableRow(mContext);
        textView = new TextView(mContext);
        textView.setTextColor(mTextColor);
        textView.setBackground(borderDrawable(mTextViewBorderWidth));
        textView.setText(tableData.field_options.options.get(h).label);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setPadding(0, 6, 0, 6);
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        tableRow.addView(textView);
        addView(tableRow);
    }

    for (int currentColumn = 0; currentColumn < tableData.field_options.options.size(); currentColumn++) {
        editText = new EditText(mContext);
        tableRow = new TableRow(mContext);
        editText.setTextColor(mTextColor);
        editText.setBackground(borderDrawable(mTextViewBorderWidth));
        editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        editText.setPadding(0, 6, 0, 6);
        tableRow.addView(editText);
        addView(tableRow);
    }

}
```

And what I want is this:

[image]

I hope someone can help me to solve this view. I don't know how to solve this problem. I tried a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think changing these 2 tables programmatically is your problem, this is of course not the wrong way but probably harder way. You can prepare 2 tables in your XML file. One table is for portrait mode, vertical table. Other one is for landscape mode, horizontal table. You can work much more easily with this way. You can check the phone orientation and make visible the desired table, make gone the other table runtime. Or you can prepare 2 separate layouts also for portrait mode and landscape mode also.

Comment: Yes, but the header are always dynamic. So sometimes there are three headers and sometime 7 of more. So I have to make it dynamic. That is why I do it on this way.